# Comparison of two variables

Tags: inequality, comparative-statics

I have a model where I have to compare the values of y(x) and z(x).

But expressions are complex and what I am getting is
$x= f(y(x))= \frac{\sin({y(x)}) + \sqrt{(y(x))^3}}{(\frac{y(x)}{1-y(x)}) ^{1/4}}$

and $x= g(z(x))$ is some complex equation just like f(y(x))

Can I compare x-f(y(x)) and x-g(z(x))? Will it be equivalent of comparing y(x) and z(x)?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would actually showcase problem, for example if you have x=g(z(x)) for all we know that function could just be x =2+2x where z(x)=2x and g(h) = 2+h, if this would be the case you can just solve for x in terms of parameters and compare which x value is larger.

Comment: @1muflon1 I have edited the question. Hope it give some sense to the problem I am asking

Comment: Can yo define what each of the functions are? Without any structure, the answer to your questions is “not in general”, but for some types of functions such tricks can be used. So you need to provide more context.

Comment: If you have the actual functions, but they are too complex for you to reasonably calculate, try using Mathematica.

Comment: @BB King I tried that and it still gave me the answers in complex hypergeometric function equations